# Having hard time understanding Forms from laravel collectives

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-blade

I'm new to Laravel.  I've created a form and trying to delete one of the `post`. I just want to know how [opening a form from Laravel collectives](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.x/html#opening-a-form) works.

Currently, this is how my form looks like in `show.blade.php`

```dart
   {!! Form::open(['action' => ['PostsController@destroy', $post->id], 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'pull-right']) !!}
    {{ Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE') }}
    {{ Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) }}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

The above form gives me the error `Action PostsController@destroy not defined.`

But when I add `'url' => 'posts/'` in Form i.e.

```dart
    {!! Form::open(['url' => 'posts/', 'action' => ['PostsController@destroy', $post->id], 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'pull-right']) !!}
```

The above error disappears.

Below is the `destroy()` function in `PostsController`

```dart
class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $post->delete();
        return redirect('/posts')->with('success','Post removed');
    }
}
```

`web.php`

```dart
// --- Posts Routing
Route::get('/posts', [App\Http\Controllers\PostsController::class, 'index'])->name('posts');
```

**MY QUESTIONS**

- I'm redirecting in the  `destroy()` function in `PostsController`, why `url` is necessary with `action` in Form from *Laravel
  collectives* to avoid the above error?
- When to use 'url' and when to use action?

I've laravel 4.2.10.

[image]

Comment: Which version of collectives do you have?

Comment: Can you add name option to your route file and try to use this option: Form::open(['route' => ['posts.delete', $post->id]]) and change your route name to posts.delete

Comment: do you have `PostsController@destroy` registered in `web.php`?

Comment: I've laravel 4.2.10.

Comment: @BhaumikPandhi this my web.php
https://ctxt.io/2/AABgdR1qFQ

Comment: @BhaumikPandhi I'm not sure how to route `destroy` in `web.php` because I'm redirecting inside `PostsController@destroy`